# Binding all System Colors to a ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I'd like to bind all Windows.UI.Colors to a ListBox (ListView?) in a XAML Page, in a Universal Windows App (for Windows 10, in Visual Studio 2015).

[I found](http://windowsapptutorials.com/tips/general-tips/get-a-list-of-all-system-colors-in-c/) this way to get all system colors:

```
Dictionary<string, Windows.UI.Color> Colors()
{
    var _Colors = typeof(Windows.UI.Colors)
        // using System.Reflection;
        .GetRuntimeProperties()
        .Select(c => new
        {
            Color = (Windows.UI.Color)c.GetValue(null),
            Name = c.Name
        });
    return _Colors.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Color);
}
```

I don't know how to bind it to a ListBox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind colors}" >
</ListBox>
```

Ideally the list item text should be the color name, and the list item background the color value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is couple of things you need to improve about binding (and I would advise to read some more [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx)). As for your code - in xaml you will need to declare how your *ItemTemplate* will look like and bind to a property within *DataContext*. You will also need probably a converter to convert *Color* to *Brush*:

```xml
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyColors}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <local:ColorToBrush x:Key="ColorToBrush"/>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrush}}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

And the code behind - converter class, the suitable property and setting *DataContext* in constructor:

```cs
public class ColorToBrush : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => new SolidColorBrush((Windows.UI.Color)value);
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    // this is the shortcut of {get { return ... }}
    public Array MyColors => typeof(Windows.UI.Colors).GetRuntimeProperties()
            .Select(c => new
            {
                Color = (Windows.UI.Color)c.GetValue(null),
                Name = c.Name
            }).ToArray();  

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Of course you can also bind to *Dictionary*, then you will have to exchange in XAML bindings: `Name -> Key` and `Color -> Value`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I will follow your suggestion regarding improving my knowledge about binding. Just a quick question: do you see any performance differences between your solution and the other one offered by @Leigh Shepperson?

Comment: @Jamrelian As for performance, I doubt you see any difference, if you want to make some 'research; use *stopwatch* class and just measure it. Nevertheless everything depends on your needs, if you want to use brush(for example show colors, use as foreground and so on), then I would follow Leigh's answer, in case you need to use brush elswhere, then you don't need to make another casting/brush creation. In case you need colors for something else then use colors.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach to @Romasz's answer:

Change the `Color()` method to a property, and return a dictionary with `SolidColorBrush` values instead of `Color` like so:

```
  public Dictionary<string, SolidColorBrush> Colors
        {
            get
            {
                var _Colors = typeof(Windows.UI.Colors)
                    // using System.Reflection;
                    .GetRuntimeProperties()
                    .Select(c => new
                    {
                        Color = new SolidColorBrush((Windows.UI.Color)c.GetValue(null)),
                        Name = c.Name
                    });

                return _Colors.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Color);
            }
        }
```

Then, in the XAML, change the list box to this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind Colors}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{Binding Value}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<SystemColor> legacyBrushes = new List<SystemColor>();
            foreach(var b in this.LegacyBrushes)
            {
                SystemColor c = new SystemColor();
                c.ColorName = b;
                c.ColorBrush = Application.Current.Resources[b] as SolidColorBrush;
                legacyBrushes.Add(c);
            }

            foreach (var b in this.SystemBrushes)
            {
                SystemColor c = new SystemColor();
                c.ColorName = b;
                c.ColorBrush = Application.Current.Resources[b] as SolidColorBrush;
                legacyBrushes.Add(c);
            }

            this._lvColors.ItemsSource = legacyBrushes;
        }

        public class SystemColor
        {
            public string ColorName { get; set; }

            public SolidColorBrush ColorBrush { get; set; }
        }


        public string[] LegacyBrushes = new string[] {
            "AppBarBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarBorderThemeBrush",
            "AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarSeparatorForegroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarToggleButtonCheckedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarToggleButtonCheckedBorderThemeBrush",
            "AppBarToggleButtonCheckedDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarToggleButtonCheckedDisabledBorderThemeBrush",
            "AppBarToggleButtonCheckedDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarToggleButtonCheckedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarToggleButtonCheckedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarToggleButtonCheckedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "AppBarToggleButtonCheckedPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarToggleButtonCheckedPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "AppBarToggleButtonCheckedPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "AppBarToggleButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ApplicationPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ApplicationPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush",
            "AutoSuggestBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "BackButtonBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "BackButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "BackButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "BackButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "BackButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "BackButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ButtonBorderThemeBrush",
            "ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush",
            "ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxBorderThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxContentDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxContentForegroundThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxForegroundThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "CheckBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxArrowDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxArrowForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxArrowPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxBorderThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxFocusedBorderThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxFocusedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxHeaderForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxItemSelectedDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxItemSelectedDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxPlaceholderTextForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxPopupBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxPopupBorderThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxPopupForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxPressedHighlightThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ComboBoxSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ContentDialogBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ContentDialogBorderThemeBrush",
            "ContentDialogContentForegroundBrush",
            "ContentDialogDimmingThemeBrush",
            "DatePickerHeaderForegroundThemeBrush",
            "DatePickerForegroundThemeBrush",
            "DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush",
            "FlipViewButtonBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "FlipViewButtonBorderThemeBrush",
            "FlipViewButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "FlipViewButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "FlipViewButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "FlipViewButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "FlipViewButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "FlipViewButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "FlipViewButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "FlyoutBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "FlyoutBorderThemeBrush",
            "FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush",
            "FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush",
            "HyperlinkButtonBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "HyperlinkButtonBorderThemeBrush",
            "HyperlinkDisabledThemeBrush",
            "HyperlinkForegroundThemeBrush",
            "HyperlinkPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "HyperlinkPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "HubSectionHeaderPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "HubSectionHeaderPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateForegroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidatePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidatePointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateSelectedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateListBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateListPagingButtonBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateListPagingButtonBorderThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateListPagingButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateListPagingButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateListPagingButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateListPagingButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "IMECandidateListPagingButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "JumpListDefaultEnabledForeground",
            "JumpListDefaultEnabledBackground",
            "JumpListDefaultDisabledForeground",
            "JumpListDefaultDisabledBackground",
            "ListBoxBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxBorderThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxFocusBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxItemSelectedDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxItemSelectedDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListBoxItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListPickerFlyoutPresenterSelectedItemForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListPickerFlyoutPresenterSelectedItemBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewGroupHeaderForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewGroupHeaderPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewGroupHeaderPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "LoopingSelectorForegroundThemeBrush",
            "LoopingSelectorSelectionBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "LoopingSelectorSelectionForegroundThemeBrush",
            "MediaButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "MediaButtonBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "MediaButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "MediaButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "MediaButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "MediaButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "MediaButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "MediaControlPanelVideoThemeBrush",
            "MediaControlPanelAudioThemeBrush",
            "MediaDownloadProgressIndicatorThemeBrush",
            "MediaErrorBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "MediaTextThemeBrush",
            "MenuFlyoutItemFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "MenuFlyoutItemFocusedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "MenuFlyoutItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "MenuFlyoutItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "MenuFlyoutItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "MenuFlyoutItemPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "MenuFlyoutItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "PivotForegroundThemeBrush",
            "PivotHeaderBackgroundSelectedBrush",
            "PivotHeaderBackgroundUnselectedBrush",
            "PivotHeaderForegroundSelectedBrush",
            "PivotHeaderForegroundUnselectedBrush",
            "PivotNavButtonBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "PivotNavButtonBorderThemeBrush",
            "PivotNavButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "PivotNavButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "PivotNavButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "PivotNavButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "PivotNavButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "PivotNavButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "PivotNavButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "MenuFlyoutSeparatorThemeBrush",
            "ProgressBarBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ProgressBarBorderThemeBrush",
            "ProgressBarForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ProgressBarIndeterminateForegroundThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonBorderThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonContentDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonContentForegroundThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "RadioButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "RepeatButtonBorderThemeBrush",
            "RepeatButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "RepeatButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush",
            "RepeatButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "RepeatButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "RepeatButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "RepeatButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "RepeatButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "RepeatButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarPanningBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarPanningBorderThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarThumbBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarThumbBorderThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarTrackBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ScrollBarTrackBorderThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxBorderThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxDisabledTextThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxPointerOverTextThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxFocusedTextThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxFocusedBorderThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxSeparatorSuggestionForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxHitHighlightForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxHitHighlightSelectedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxIMECandidateListSeparatorThemeBrush",
            "SearchBoxForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SemanticZoomButtonBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SemanticZoomButtonBorderThemeBrush",
            "SemanticZoomButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SemanticZoomButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SemanticZoomButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "SemanticZoomButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SemanticZoomButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SemanticZoomButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "SemanticZoomButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SettingsFlyoutBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SettingsFlyoutBackButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SettingsFlyoutHeaderBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SettingsFlyoutHeaderForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderBorderThemeBrush",
            "SliderDisabledBorderThemeBrush",
            "SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderThumbBorderThemeBrush",
            "SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "SliderThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "SliderTickMarkInlineBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTickMarkInlineDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTrackBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTrackDecreaseBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTrackDecreaseDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTrackDecreasePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTrackDecreasePressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "SliderHeaderForegroundThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxForegroundHeaderThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxBorderThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxButtonBorderThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ThumbBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ThumbBorderThemeBrush",
            "ThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "ThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "TimePickerHeaderForegroundThemeBrush",
            "TimePickerForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonBorderThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonCheckedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonCheckedBorderThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonCheckedDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonCheckedDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonCheckedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonCheckedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonCheckedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonCheckedPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonCheckedPressedBorderThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonCheckedPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchCurtainBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchCurtainDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchCurtainPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchCurtainPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchHeaderDisabledForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchHeaderForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchOuterBorderBorderThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchOuterBorderDisabledBorderThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchThumbBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchThumbBorderThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchThumbDisabledBorderThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchThumbPressedForegroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchTrackBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchTrackBorderThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToggleSwitchTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToolTipBackgroundThemeBrush",
            "ToolTipBorderThemeBrush",
            "ToolTipForegroundThemeBrush",
        };

        public string[] SystemBrushes = new string[] {
            "SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundAltMediumHighBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundAltMediumLowBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundBaseHighBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumHighBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundChromeBlackHighBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundChromeBlackMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundListLowBrush",
            "SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlDisabledAccentBrush",
            "SystemControlDisabledBaseHighBrush",
            "SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush",
            "SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush",
            "SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledHighBrush",
            "SystemControlDisabledChromeDisabledLowBrush",
            "SystemControlDisabledChromeHighBrush",
            "SystemControlDisabledChromeMediumLowBrush",
            "SystemControlDisabledListMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundAltMediumHighBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackHighBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundChromeMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundChromeWhiteBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundChromeDisabledLowBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundListLowBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundListMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackMediumLowBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltAccentBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltAltHighBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltBaseLowBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumLowBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltListAccentHighBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltListAccentLowBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltListAccentMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightAltTransparentBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightBaseLowBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumHighBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightChromeAltLowBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightChromeHighBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush",
            "SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush",
            "SystemControlHyperlinkTextBrush",
            "SystemControlHyperlinkBaseHighBrush",
            "SystemControlHyperlinkBaseMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlHyperlinkBaseMediumHighBrush",
            "SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlPageBackgroundBaseLowBrush",
            "SystemControlPageBackgroundBaseMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlPageBackgroundListLowBrush",
            "SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush",
            "SystemControlPageTextBaseHighBrush",
            "SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush",
            "SystemControlPageTextChromeBlackMediumLowBrush",
        };

        private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            rootFrame.RequestedTheme = cb.IsChecked.Value ? ElementTheme.Dark : ElementTheme.Light;
        }
```

```
<ListView Name="_lvColors" SelectionMode="None" Margin="0 30 0 0">
            
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="48">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColorName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" Margin="10 0"/>

                        <Grid Background="{Binding ColorBrush}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>

        <CheckBox Content="Theme" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it solves the question asked.